# Use 2D lists and while loop to create multiplication table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to use three while loops to create a 2D list of the multiplication table. 
The instruction does not allow me to create another list.

I am able to create two nested list in a list. 
My major concern is how to multiply two nested list together and gather the outcome. I hope to get some advice here.

```
MT = [[],[]]
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

while num1 < 10:
    num1 = num1 + 1
    MT[0].append(num1)
    while num2 < 10:
        num2 = num2 + 1
        MT[1].append(num2)

print(MT)
```

I hope to get my outcome like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0eTM.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do:

```
M = [['X', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
for i in range(1, 11):
  row = [i]
  for j in range(1, 11):
    row.append(i*j)
  M.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to fill the multiplication table with while-loops (as you said) and not with for-loops you can do it like this:

```
MT = [[] for i in range(11)]
MT[0].append('X')
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

# fill the multiplication table
while num1 < 10:
  num1 = num1 + 1
  MT[0].append(num1)
  MT[num1].append(num1)
  while num2 < 10:
    num2 = num2 + 1
    MT[num1].append(num1*num2)
  num2 = 0

# print the multiplication table
for row in MT:
  for e in row:
    print(e, end="\t")
  print()
```